# What splitter should I use for every other line?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text file that contains data every other line. I want to get the content of every non-empty line. Given the whole text of the file, I first tried using `myText.split("\n\n")`. To my surprise, it does not work. I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows uses *CRLF* as line separators. And you are splitting on *LF*. That wouldn't work.

A safe way is to use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to get the appropriate separator on your OS.

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
myText.split("(?:" + newLine + ")+");
```

---

It might be possible that you are reading a file created on a different OS. Then the above method won't work. A better way would be use a character class with `CR` and `LF`, as specified in comments by @Marko:

```
myText.split("[\r\n]+");
```

Comment: that only works if the text is actually from the same os that java is running on (usually the case, but not always the case), if the text can be from anywhere (windows / linux / mac). it would be better to split by `\n` and trim `\r` of every line

Comment: Or use a generalized expression which covers all cases? Like `"[\r\n]+"`. Maybe even a Unicode category for newlines.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that is the best solution in my opinion

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. That's a better option. Edited into the answer :)